# Appengine can't retrieve Entities from datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I got appengine all set up, and it workds on my localhost, I call

```
Entity greeting3 = new Entity(KeyFactory.createKey("World", "world3"));
greeting3.setProperty("raw", "2.2 # # # .");
datastore.put(greeting3);
```

to add my entities, and I can see them added in the console. I then use

```
Query q = new Query("World");
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
    resp.getWriter().println(result);
}
```

to retrieve the entities. it works perfect on localhost, but on the server I just can't receive the list of all added entities. they do get added though with the first code. I also use

```
e = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("World", req.getParameter(k)));
resp.getWriter().println(e.getProperty("raw"));
```

and on localhost it works as well, but on the internet, it throws 'no entity found exception'. I've tried manually added datastore indexes but it did not help.
I've been working all day and it really upsets me now :( I'm also quite sure it worked yesterday... 
please help
thanks

Comment: Check that `req.getParameter(k)` is actually `"world3"`.

Comment: it has name/id world3 on loacalhost, but on google it's got name=world3 "tag". but also shouldn't datastore.prepare(q); return all World entities?

Comment: @zavr did my answer helped?

Comment: @xybrek i don't think so, I ended up creating a new app

Answer (score 0):

If your query is run very soon after you put the entity in the datastore, this issue could be because the app engine datastore is not "[immediately consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_consistency)". It is "[eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)"

You can test this by waiting a few seconds (maybe 10?) before running your query.

If this was the bug, then you should check out the app engine datastore overview in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview)

Comment: unfortunately it wasn't the case as it's been more than 10 hours still the entities were added and it still does not work. Also I can see then in the admin, but can't retrieve using the datastore API. I will try create new project and use datastore in it, see what happens. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this also, if its not that `req.getParameter(k)` is something else other than what you expected, then you just have to run the query again. Datastore is not really fast, that is why there is Memcache.

If you want your application to serve data immediately then, you have to "cache" it using the Memcache API.